# How can I save document in mongo in camel case using c#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

How can I save document in mongo in camel case? Now i am trying to save this:

```
  "parent_template_id": "5aa7822ba6adf805741c5722",
  "type": "Mutable",
  "subject": {
    "workspace_id": "5-DKC0PV8U",
    "additional_data": {
      "boardId": "149018",
    }
```

but boardId transform into board_id in db (snake case).
This is my field in c#:

```
[BsonElement("additional_data")]
[BsonIgnoreIfNull]
public Dictionary<string, string> AdditionalData { get; set; }
```

Comment: Just in case anybody lands here from a Google search (like I did), what the question really asks is *snake_case*, not *camelCase*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to register a new serializer that will deal with your senario, thankfully this libary is very extentionable so you'll only need to write a few parts where you need to extend it.

So to start off with you'll need to create a `Serializer` to write your string keys as underscore case:

```
public class UnderscoreCaseStringSerializer : StringSerializer
{
    public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, string value)
    {
        value = string.Concat(value.Select((x, i) => i > 0 && char.IsUpper(x) ? "_" + x.ToString() : x.ToString())).ToLower();

        base.Serialize(context, args, value);
    }
}
```

Now we've got a serializer to work with we can register a new dictionary serializer in the bson serializer registry with our new `UnderscoreCaseStringSerializer` to be used for serialzing the key:

```
var customSerializer =
    new DictionaryInterfaceImplementerSerializer<Dictionary<string, string>>
        (DictionaryRepresentation.Document, new UnderscoreCaseStringSerializer(), new ObjectSerializer());

BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(customSerializer);
```

And that's it...

```
internal class MyDocument
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> AdditionalData { get; set; }
}

var collection = new MongoClient().GetDatabase("test").GetCollection<MyDocument>("docs");

var myDocument = new MyDocument
{
    Name = "test",
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["boardId"] = "149018"
    }
};

collection.InsertOne(myDocument);

// { "_id" : ObjectId("5b74093fbbbca64ba8ce9d0e"), "name" : "test", "additional_data" : { "board_id" : "149018" } }
```

You might also want to consider using a `ConventionPack` to deal with your conventions of having underscores for field names, this just means that you don't need to litter your classes with `BsonElement` attributes and it will just work by convention.

```
public class UnderscoreCaseElementNameConvention : ConventionBase, IMemberMapConvention
{
    public void Apply(BsonMemberMap memberMap)
    {
        string name = memberMap.MemberName;
        name = string.Concat(name.Select((x, i) => i > 0 && char.IsUpper(x) ? "_" + x.ToString() : x.ToString())).ToLower();
        memberMap.SetElementName(name);
    }
}

var pack = new ConventionPack();
pack.Add(new UnderscoreCaseElementNameConvention());

ConventionRegistry.Register(
    "My Custom Conventions",
    pack,
    t => true);
```

Comment: Thank you! For this purpose, the convention went very well. The json database is stored in camelCase now. But setting ProcessDictionaryKeys in Startup was true, and I got a snake. I switch ProcessDictionaryKeys to false, and now everything is fine) (when i trying get stored data)

Comment: I'm a bit confused how a convention is created on what seems to be a global level? How does this work?

Comment: @ThierryProst It's in a global register, however, the `t => true` in the example is where you'd scope it t certain types/namespaces.